# How do I go back to motherbase in MGS:TPP?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I am playing MGSV:TPP but i want to go to motherbase sometimes instead of just wandering in afghanistan, does anyone know how I go there?

Answer (score 8):

If you're on the ground, you first need to get to your helicopter. You can do this by opening your iDroid, pressing up/down on the map screen to select the helicopter pickup option, then mark the landing point you'd like the helicopter to land at. Once you've done that, go to the location you specified and hop on the helicopter.

Once you're in your helicopter (ACC), at the bottom of the right-most tab of your iDroid you'll see a "Return to Motherbase" option. It's as simple as selecting that.

Comment: @WezeldeStenheid Mark the answer as accepted if it was useful

Comment: It's a lot easier to open the options menu (opposite button from iDroid) and select "return to ACC".

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer It's also not gameplay related and feels exploity since you can do it for no cost whatsoever and at any time, and it doesn't even save the game.

Comment: ' and it doesn't even save the game.' that is your cost, but feel free not to use it, however it should be noted since it's for factual basis as part of the answer i think

Comment: thanks again guys, i just don't want to wander around in Afghanistan all the time lol.

Comment: @WezeldeStenheid You might want to read the tutorials next time, so you don't run into this kind of problem again. And don't forget to accept this answer if it was useful.

Comment: And *do take a shower when you get back to MotherBase*...